# Checking if file and folder exists in Linux console

Tags: linux, shell, command

I'm not the most advanced user so i'm trying simple solutions yet they does not seem to work.  I want to create script that does 2 things.

1. Creates project file, if it exists it removes it and creates new one.

   ```
   if [ -f projekt ]
   then
     rmdir projekt
     mkdir projekt
   else 
     mkdir projekt
   fi
   ```
2. Reads file name, if it exists it asks for new one as long as you give proper name. Then i need to use that name but i figured it out. I want to create file in home folder that's why `~/`.

   ```
   read name

   while [ -f ~/$name ]
   do
     echo "File exists " | read name
   done
   ```

In first case it just ignores "if" and says that file exists, in second case it just goes in weird infinite loop if file exists.

I know it's probably incredible easy but i'm thinking how to fix it for 1,5 hours and i have no idea what's wrong.

Edit

I have managed to fix it. -f stands for file, so it should be changed to -d. ~/$name can be changed to $name because we are pretty much standing in the same directory. And | should be removed and read name moved to next line. I'm not sure why it's not working with | though.

Comment: `while [ f ~/$name ]` does not look correct. I would expect to see `while [ -f "$HOME/$name" ]`. What does Shellcheck have to say? Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: I have managed to fix it but thanks for help.